# Hide a button if the link in associated iframe does not exist

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a way to hide a button if the link in an iframe associated with it does not exist.

My html looks a little like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
<title>Day Chooser</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='menu-files/style.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='menu-files/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='menu-files/jquery.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">

        <div id="menu">

        <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"     id="showmonday">Monday</a></li>
                 <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="showtuesday">Tuesday</a></li>
                  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="showwednesday">Wednesday</a></li>
                   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="showthursday">Thursday</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="showfriday">Friday</a></li>
                     <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="showsaturday">Saturday</a></li>
                      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="showsunday">Sunday</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>


        <div id="iframe">
            <div id="monday"><h1>Monday</h1><iframe src="monday/album/index.html" frameborder="0" style="height:779px; width:1024px;"></iframe></div>
             <div id="tuesday"><h1>Tuesday</h1><iframe src="tuesday/album/index.html" frameborder="0" style="height:779px; width:1024px;"></iframe></div>
              <div id="wednesday"><h1>Wednesday</h1><iframe src="wednesday/album/index.html" frameborder="0" style="height:779px; width:1024px;"></iframe></div>
               <div id="thursday"><h1>Thursday</h1><iframe src="thursday/album/index.html" frameborder="0" style="height:779px; width:1024px;"></iframe></div>
                <div id="friday"><h1>Friday</h1><iframe src="friday/album/index.html" frameborder="0" style="height:779px; width:1024px;"></iframe></div>
                 <div id="saturday"><h1>Saturday</h1><iframe src="saturday/album/index.html" frameborder="0" style="height:779px; width:1024px;"></iframe></div>
                  <div id="sunday"><h1>Sunday</h1><iframe src="sunday/album/index.html" frameborder="0" style="height:779px; width:1024px;"></iframe></div>
        </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The js code looks like this

```
idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
//Increment the idle time counter every minute.
var idleInterval = setInterval("timerIncrement()", 60000); // 1 minute

//Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
$(this).mousemove(function (e) {
    idleTime = 0;
});
$(this).keypress(function (e) {
    idleTime = 0;
});
})
function timerIncrement() {
idleTime = idleTime + 1;
if (idleTime > 1) { // 20 minutes
    window.location.reload();
}
}



 $(function(){

 $('#showfrontpage').click(function(){
 $('#frontpage').show();
 $('#monday').hide();
 $('#wednesday').hide(); 
 $('#tuesday').hide();
     $('#thursday').hide();
     $('#friday').hide();
     $('#saturday').hide();
     $('#sunday').hide();
 });
 $('#showmonday').click(function(){
 $('#frontpage').hide();
 $('#monday').show();
 $('#wednesday').hide(); 
 $('#tuesday').hide();
     $('#thursday').hide();
     $('#friday').hide();
     $('#saturday').hide();
     $('#sunday').hide();
 });
 $('#showtuesday').click(function(){
 $('#frontpage').hide();
 $('#monday').hide();
 $('#wednesday').hide(); 
 $('#tuesday').show();
     $('#thursday').hide();
     $('#friday').hide();
     $('#saturday').hide();
     $('#sunday').hide();
 });
 $('#showwednesday').click(function(){
 $('#frontpage').hide();
 $('#monday').hide();
 $('#wednesday').show(); 
 $('#tuesday').hide();
     $('#thursday').hide();
     $('#friday').hide();
     $('#saturday').hide();
     $('#sunday').hide();
  });
 $('#showthursday').click(function(){
 $('#frontpage').hide();
 $('#monday').hide();
 $('#wednesday').hide(); 
 $('#tuesday').hide();
     $('#thursday').show();
     $('#friday').hide();
     $('#saturday').hide();
     $('#sunday').hide();
 });
 $('#showfriday').click(function(){
 $('#frontpage').hide();
 $('#monday').hide();
 $('#wednesday').hide(); 
 $('#tuesday').hide();
     $('#thursday').hide();
     $('#friday').show();
     $('#saturday').hide();
     $('#sunday').hide();
 });
 $('#showsaturday').click(function(){
 $('#frontpage').hide();
 $('#monday').hide();
 $('#wednesday').hide(); 
 $('#tuesday').hide();
     $('#thursday').hide();
     $('#friday').hide();
     $('#saturday').show();
     $('#sunday').hide();
 });
 $('#showsunday').click(function(){
 $('#frontpage').hide();
 $('#monday').hide();
 $('#wednesday').hide(); 
 $('#tuesday').hide();
     $('#thursday').hide();
     $('#friday').hide();
     $('#saturday').hide();
     $('#sunday').show();
 });

 });
```

The code at the top of the js is just a timer which reloads the menu after time if there is no mouse moment.

The other js code hides all the iframes except the one selected, in the css there is code that hides all the iframes until they are selected.

What I also need to happen is for the menu buttons to be hidden and only show if the link in it's associated iframe exists.

All the existing code works, I just need the last bit then I'm done with this.

One last thing, all this needs to work locally with no server, the code above does work locally.

Comment: You should look into using classes. All those `hide()` statements targeting ID's could be shortened up.

Comment: Adding classes would also enable adding more very easy

Comment: Thanks @tymeJV I will look in to using classes.  I am very new to all types of code only started a couple of weeks ago, apart from school in the eighty's when we were using **Basic** ;-)

Comment: @RoyHollister -- Much has changed :D Keep at it though, you'll pick it up quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using jQuery's [`.find` method](http://api.jquery.com/find/). [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/2vk5C/). In the demo I commented out Monday's iframe to show it works

I updated your code to include classes to make it much shorter and easier to deal with, but if you don't do it with classes it's the same method, just repeated for each id

Updated jQuery based on the classes I added:

```
$(function(){
    // This is the part that your question is about - hiding the li if there is
    // no corresponding iframe
    $('.show').each(function() {
        var dayButton = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
        if($('.day.'+ dayButton).find('iframe').length == 0)
        {
            $('.show.'+ dayButton).hide();
        }
    });

    // This is the part you already had, just in class form so it's shorter
    $('.day').each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });                   
    $('.show').click(function() {
        var dayClicked = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]
        $('.day').each(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $('.day.' + dayClicked).show();
    });
});
```

You simply need to style the jsFiddle I made using your CSS from your project and it should work perfectly

Comment: Okay, thanks @Zeaklous I had to add a little code so that my menu would hide when an iframe was shown and so the menu would show again when asked. I'm not to sure how to show that code in this comment box, I'll work that out latter.  Thanks for your help, the code is so much tidier now.  I'm still not having much luck with having the buttons hide when an iframe link is missing, I have read that jquery and or java script will not work locally.

Comment: My result with the basic style so you can see what is happening.  Does not show perfect on JSFIDDLE but close enough for this..http://jsfiddle.net/Roy_Hollister/xmB6A/1/

Comment: That looks great! You should consider scrolling the screen to the top when a day is selected as well. For example if you click Sunday you can't see part of the iframe that is up top. I'd make the page scroll to where all of it is visible on click. Good work!